# Counting files between two corresponding strings in multiple directories

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let's say I have some directories which contain files. For example, the directories

```
/home/me/files/files_10
/home/me/files/files_11
/home/me/files/files_12
```

each of which contains some files corresponding to the last digits. For example, the directory /home/me/files/files_10 contains files

```
/home/me/files/files_10/file_100.txt
/home/me/files/files_10/file_102.txt
/home/me/files/files_10/file_105.txt
/home/me/files/files_10/file_106.txt
etc
```

The file numbers do grow larger, but do not necessarily include each digit (as 101, 103, 104 are missing in this case).

I am seeking to count the number of files between two inputted values. Given the example above, if my first value was 100 and my second value was 105, I would like the output to be 3. If the first value was 103 and the second value was 106, I would like the output to be 2. Furthermore, let's say I give a first value of 112 and a second value of 125. I would like to go into the corresponding directories (ending with 11 and 12), and count the number of files between these two values.

This is a simplified version of what I'm working with, but is functionally equivalent. What scheme could accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: won't we have more than 10 files in a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 ls /home/test/files/*/file_{112..125}.txt 2> /dev/null | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow-up question: if I wanted to save the outputted count to a variable, how would I do that?

Comment: @theta: `somevariable="$( somecommand )"`

Answer (score 2):

You could of course use `find` but also less frequently used `updatedb`
and `locate`.

First, we need to use `updatedb` to create a database of existing
files that subsequent `locate` commands will use. Go to
`/home/me/files` and do:

```
updatedb --require-visibility 0 -o locate.db -U .
```

Now we're ready to use `locate` in conjunction with Bash `{a..b}`
syntax to search for a list of files. For example:

```
$ locate -d ./locate.db file_{112..125}.txt
./files_11/file_112.txt
./files_11/file_113.txt
./files_12/file_124.txt
./files_12/file_125.txt
$ locate -d ./locate.db file_{100..105}.txt
./files_10/file_100.txt
./files_10/file_102.txt
./files_10/file_105.txt
$ locate -d ./locate.db file_{103..106}.txt
./files_10/file_105.txt
./files_10/file_106.txt
```

To show only a number of found files pipe `locate` output through `wc -l`.

The advantage of this solution is that `locate` works very fast.

The disadvantage is that you will have re-create the database manually
each time new files are added or renamed (or maybe use `inotify`) and
that `locate` cannot replace found filenames with NUL which will
cause `wc -l` to return incorrect count in case of files that have a
new line in their names.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking to count the numbered files from x to y included:

```bash
$ tree files/
files/
├── file_100.txt
├── file_102.txt
├── file_105.txt
└── file_106.txt

0 directories, 4 files


$ start=103; end=106; echo files/* \
  | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' \
  | awk '{ if ($1 >='$start' && $1 <= '$end') {++count}} END { print count }'
2
```

But if you are really sure there are no spaces or linebreaks in your filenames,
@msp9011's answer is way easier...

Comment: @Freddy : fixed, thanks!